# ezPDF reader: settings to correct jerky page scrolling?

Tags: settings, pdf

On the ezPDF Reader, is there a way to make the scrolling from one page to another smoother and less jerky? Some settings, perhaps? The jerky/jumping scrolling on ezPDF reader when one page scrolls to the next page breaks the flow of reading a little. Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just received an email from the developer, Don Choi. Citing it here in its entirety as an answer:

> The continuous scroll feature is in our big  TO-DO list. It will
>   eventually implemented later.We do not have a open forum. However,
>   http://www.facebook.com/ezpdf is a good start.

So more nifty things are on their way for this application.

Comment: that's good news. Considering how often it gets updated, hopefully it won't be too long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about scrolling smoothly, but if you tap the bottom of the screen as you're reading it automatically scrolls up or to the next page as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, it is helpful. I guess it will have to do till the developer implements the continuous  scrolling.